# conversion from string Update Users Set Credit= to type Double is not valid

Tags: android, dependencies

i had put the proguard rules in my app but still when i decompile the app with dex2ar i see that in the app class my variables that store my vital data like webservice url, salt and... are shown.
can any one tell me that what is the rule for the these dependencies?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
```

Comment: When you proguard any application it will hide your loops, condition and variable name but not able to hide your static string value like URL,Resources and if you want to hide your URL create one separate project encrypt your url with some algorithm and  and implement decrypt logic in your project and use that decrypted URL

Comment: i think that my rules was not corrected. i want to know the correct rules first and then if it was not changed then i will do theway you say @jack

Comment: Please clarify what you want

Comment: i want the proguard rules for these dependencies that are shown on the top @Jack